# Closely monitoring charging (with bike charger)

Tags: battery, charging

I bought a bike charger for my Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro sk17i . When I cycle, the phone says that it is being charged, but apparently it is not because the battery percentage doesn't increase.

It is hard to find out anything with the built in battery utility. Is there any way to monitor charging more closely, such as reading the charging current or some other useful indicators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Battery Monitor Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.bmw) or similar might report the current (it depends on whether the battery controller reports it or not), though I'm not finding any reports on whether it works on your device or not.  Still, can't hurt to try it.

Alternatively, a USB multimeter, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DF2485S), would give you definite readings.